# Different query generated if there is a literal

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using MySQl 5.5.19, entity framework 4.3, and have tried both the Sun-provided MySQL connector and the DevArt one without any difference between the two.

So, I've got two statements which produce different queries.  The first is:

```
var desserts = context.desserts
    .AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
    .Where(m => m.FlavorId == 123)
    .ToList();
```

and the second is

```
var desserts = context.desserts
    .AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
    .Where(m => m.FlavorId == someFlavorId)
    .ToList();
```

The first query produces a SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  Extent1.Id,
  Extent1.Name,
  Extent1.FlavorId
FROM icecream.dessert AS Extent1
WHERE Extent1.FlavorId = 123
ORDER BY Extent1.Id ASC
```

The second one produces a much more costly query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  Project1.Id,
  Project1.Name,
  Project1.FlavorId
  FROM(
    SELECT
      Extent1.Id,
      Extent1.Name,
      Extent1.FlavorId
    FROM icecream.dessert AS Extent1
    WHERE Extent1.FlavorId = 123
  ) AS Project1
  ORDER BY Project1.Id ASC
```

And, of course, the latter query is the one that is used in my production code.  I'm confused why these two result in a different query.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They produce different sql, because the first query you are passing in a constant and the second one you are passing in a parameter.

If you want to mimic the first query you would need to create an Expression for the Where predicate like this:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dessert), "d");
Expression propertyOrField = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter , "FlavorId");
Expression constant = Expression.Constant(someFlavorId, typeof(long?));
Expression equal = Expression.Equal(propertyOrField, constant);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dessert, bool>>(equal, parameter);

var desserts = context.desserts
    .AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
    .Where(lambda)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ran EXPLAIN on the SQL produced by the second one and it isn't good - primary is of type "ALL" with 968K rows and Extra is "using filesort" and the derived uses a key and has 534K rows.  The query produced by the one with the literal is of type "ref" with 534K rows, "using where" - it is definitely slower with the non-literal query.

Comment: Also, your expression works great for a different column but this particular one ("FlavorId") is a nullable long.  Any ideas how to make it work with the nullable?

Comment: @itsmatt - Interesting, I would have thought MySql would be better at optimizing and both queries would result in the same execution plan.

Comment: @itsmatt - Do you get an error message when you try with *FlavorId* Or are the results not what they should be?

Comment: It throws InvalidOperationException "The binary operator Equal isnot defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]' and 'system.Int64'.

Comment: @itsmatt - I updated the answer with the fix, you need to use a different overload *Expression.Constant(someFlavorId, typeof(long?));*